# Add static files to HTML during build (Webpack)

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm a bit stuck

I have a script that programmatically injects manifest, vendor and app into the page on load.
I need this script to be injected into the html during the build process, but it is not necessary during development.

Here is my prod config (the default, with some very minor changes) -

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
  ? require('../config/test.env')
  : require('../config/prod.env')

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true,
      usePostCSS: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        }
      },
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      parallel: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].css'),
      // set the following option to `true` if you want to extract CSS from
      // codesplit chunks into this main css file as well.
      // This will result in *all* of your app's CSS being loaded upfront.
      allChunks: false,
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap
        ? { safe: true, map: { inline: false } }
        : { safe: true }
    }),

    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ]),

    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: false,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
    }),
    new AddAssetHtmlPlugin({
      filepath: require.resolve('../static/js/init.js'),
      publicPath: '/static/js/init.js',
      includeSourcemap: false
    }),
    // keep module.id stable when vender modules does not change
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    // enable scope hoisting
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks (module) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    // This instance extracts shared chunks from code splitted chunks and bundles them
    // in a separate chunk, similar to the vendor chunk
    // see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'app',
      async: 'vendor-async',
      children: true,
      minChunks: 3
    })
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

I need to add `static/js/init.js` into the html, but I'm not sure how to do so if the file is static, and is not a chunk. Are there any suggestions? Thanks!

I tried using add-asset-html-webpack-plugin but couldn't get it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out in the end.

I originally had `inject: false` in my `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, which was preventing `html-webpack-include-assets-plugin` from working.

To get it working I used `html-webpack-include-assets-plugin` to inject any static assets, and then in my `new HtmlWebpackPlugin` I set `chunks` to an empty array (`[]`). This meant my chunks were still compiled but not dumped into the final build HTML.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve the insertion of `static/js/init.js` in the `index.html` file generated using [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) and [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin). This also requires an html template that support adding scripts resources such as the one provided in [html-webpack-template](https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template).

Here is the necessary configuration for these *plugins*:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'path-to/node_modules/html-webpack-template/index.ejs',
        inject: false,
        scripts: ['/static/js/init.js']
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
            from: './path/to/static/js/init.js',
            to: path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, 'static/js/init.js')
        }
    ])
]
```

Here `CopyWebpackPlugin` is used to copy the static assets (script in this case) to the output build folder.
Then the output path is added to the `scripts` option of `HtmlWebpackPlugin` in order to add a `<script>` tag referencing that static asset.

You can check a working [Webpack Demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) with this configuration and other useful configs.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right and you don't want to process the file during your build process you can simply include the static `js` into your `index.html`.

Like so:

`<script src="static/js/init.js"></script>`

Comment: That means the script would be injected during development. 
But the files that `init` loads are the _build files_ that `yarn build` dumps out. So I don't want it running during that time. I only want it to be there at buildtime